# how to inject momentjs in typescript in AngularJs 1.5

Tags: angularjs, date, typescript, momentjs, angularjs-1.5

I want to inject the momentJs library in my typescript code to do operations on a Date object. But I am not familiar with injecting typescript through angularJs, since it is little different from javascript.

```js
angular.module("app")
       .config(function ($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
                return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            };
        });
```

In the above code, the `moment` function is not recognized, even though I have included the CDN.

Answer (score 1):

**1 -** Install moment with your package manager (NPM for example)

**2 -** Reference it in your entry point application file :

```
<script src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>
```

**3 -** Create a constant referencing moment as it can be used as a service (don't forget to import it) :

```
import moment = require('moment');

angular.module("app").constant("moment", moment);
```

**4 -** You should be able now to configure moment in your angular run function like this :

```
angular.run(["moment", function(moment) { moment.locale("fr")}]);
```

AND using it in your controllers aswell still using dependency injection.

**TIPS -** Using typescript you should create your application using classes like this (even if Typescript is just a superset of Javascript) :

```
class MyController implements ng.IController {

    static $inject: string[] : ["moment"];

    constructor(
        private moment) {}

    $onInit = function () {

        // do something with moment
        let date =  this.moment();        

    }

}
```

Let me know if it helps you out.

Comment: I just show this tip in order to suggest you a cleaner code using typescript and easier way to move to angular 2.

If it makes you confuse just stick with the normal way and it should

Comment: Can i just use a cdn instead of installing through npm?

Comment: Yes you can do this.

Comment: So I should skip the above  4 steps and just include , var ngModule = angular.module('ngApp',['angularMoment']);   something like this

Answer (score 0):

After you add all necessary scripts of moment.js in your page.

Use it like this and try

```js
angular.module("app")
.config(function ($mdDateLocaleProvider, moment) {
    $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
        return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add moment in config callback. You have to add moment in config callback as you have added $mdDateLocaleProvider.

There is a more popular angular-moment. you can see the steps in documentation of angular-moment. https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

let me know if any thing else is required